# Django is not redirecting after receiving a POST request

Tags: javascript, python, django, redirect

I'm trying to send some values from the front-end to a Django app. I want to manipulate those values and then redirect to another view, but it seems that Django is not redirecting nor rendering nothing.

This is my urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import settings
from personality_form import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name="home"),
    url(r'^apiLogin/(?P<_id>\d+)$', views.apiLogin,name="apiLogin"),
    url(r'^formulario/(?P<_id>\d+)$', views.formulario, name="formulario"),
]
```

This is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from personality_form.models import *
from personality_form.forms import *
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

def home(request):  
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def formulario(request, _id):
    if (request.method == 'POST'):
        form = personalityForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = personalityForm()

    return render(request, 'formulario.html', {'form': form})

@csrf_exempt
def apiLogin(request, _id):
    if (request.method == 'POST'):        
        return redirect('/formulario/'+_id)
```

And this is the javascript function that I'm using to send the POST request from the front.

```
function test() {
            var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
            http.open('POST', '/apiLogin/1234', true);
            http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
            var payload = {userID: "1234", access: "4567"};
            var params = JSON.stringify(payload);

            // Send request
            http.send(params);
        }
```

I've tried to send the POST to apiLogin view. I check that it is entering on that view but when I try to redirect to formulario view, it enters on formulario code but don't seems to execute the render instruction. I tried to change the redirect function for render but don't show the new html neither.

Is there a reason why is not redirecting the url and changing the front?

I'm using Django 1.11 and Python 3.6.

Comment: do you see any error or stacktrace?

Comment: No. The POST returns "POST /apiLogin/1234 HTTP/1.1" 302 and after that is executing the code from 'formulario' view, but it seems to ignore the render instruction, and don't change the url.

Comment: I see, are you using the javascript function to test the code?? It is correctly redirecting to the URL, but the javascript is not doing anything with that redirect instruction.

Comment: you're making an HTTP request from javascript, so the response is received by your AJAX call. Since you're only doing `http.send(params)` and not even looking at the response, nothing seems to happen. But if you look in your javascript console, you'll see the response HTTP 302 redirect.

Comment: Yes, i'm using the test javascript function to comunicate the client side with the server. What should I do to manage the response from the javascript? I was looking at it like sending a form from the HTML, that when the django app receives it you can change views o render a file. Is that vision wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your code slightly. 
In your `api_login()`, create a reverse url with an argument. Then inside your JavaScript change the window url itself to redirect.

Firstly, inside your `def apiLogin(request, _id)` :

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import JsonResponse

@csrf_exempt
def apiLogin(request, _id):
    if (request.method == 'POST'):        
        #create a url string using reverse.
        url = reverse('formulario' , kwargs = {'_id' : _id})
        #if the above way doesn't work then try: url = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('formulario' , kwargs = {'_id' : _id}))
        #Now simply return a JsonResponse. Ideally while dealing with ajax, Json is preferred. 
        return JsonResponse(status = 302 , data = {'success' : url })
```

Then inside your JavaScript:

```
function test() {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //The onreadystatechange function is called every time the readyState changes.
    //4: request finished and response is ready
    //basically the below function gets called every time your the response of you request request is returned from the server.
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 302) {
            var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText); 
            console.log(json.success);
            //following line would actually change the url of your window.  
            window.location.href = json.success; 
        }
    };
    http.open('POST', '/apiLogin/1234', true);
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
    var payload = {userID: "1234", access: "4567"};
    var params = JSON.stringify(payload);

    // Send request
    http.send(params);     
}
```

I hope this works. If it doesn't then please check what is printed inside the console. If it works then simply remove the console statement.

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks ! This works, but I had to change the status code on the javascript, because you put 302 in views.py and 301 in the javascript function. If you can please edit your answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @MaríaVictoria apologies for the typo. You are correct. It should be status 302 in both the code snippets. 301 is for permanent redirects which is not in this case.